# Cuda using template class / passing lambdas to non-class function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, cuda, nvcc

I am trying to learn Cuda programming and have written a couple test programs in the process.  The first of these works as I expected:

ts0.cu:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T, typename F>
__global__ void do_op(T *a, T *b, T *c, F f)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;

    c[i] = f(a[i], b[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int b[] = {4, 5, 6};
    int c[sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)] = {0};

    int *cudaA = 0;
    int *cudaB = 0;
    int *cudaC = 0;

    cudaMalloc(&cudaA, sizeof(a));
    cudaMalloc(&cudaB, sizeof(b));
    cudaMalloc(&cudaC, sizeof(c));

    cudaMemcpy(cudaA, a, sizeof(a), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(cudaB, b, sizeof(b), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    do_op<int><<<1, sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)>>>(cudaA, cudaB, cudaC, [] __device__(int l, int r)
                                               { return l + r; }); // nvcc has no difficulty identifying this + operator

    cudaMemcpy(c, cudaC, sizeof(b), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(c) / sizeof(int); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << (i == 0 ? '[' : ',') << c[i];
    }

    std::cout << ']' << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running yield the following:

```
$ nvcc ts0.cu --extended-lambda -o ts0
$ ./ts0 
[5,7,9]
```

I then tried wrapping the code above in a vector class I'm defining (again for learning purposes) by doing the following:

ts1.cu:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T, typename F>
__global__ void do_op(T *a, T *b, T *c, F f)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;

    c[i] = f(a[i], b[i]);
}

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class vector
{
private:
    T _v[N];

public:
    vector() : _v{0} {}

    vector(const vector<T, N> &src)
    {
        std::copy(src._v, src._v + N, this->_v);
    }

    vector(std::initializer_list<T> src)
    {
        assert(size(src) == N);
        std::copy(src.begin(), src.end(), this->_v);
    }

    friend vector<T, N> operator+(const vector<T, N> &lhs, const vector<T, N> &rhs)
    {
        vector<T, N> vec;

        T *cudaLS = 0;
        T *cudaRS = 0;
        T *cudaRV = 0;

        cudaMalloc(&cudaLS, N);
        cudaMalloc(&cudaRS, N);
        cudaMalloc(&cudaRV, N);

        cudaMemcpy(cudaLS, lhs._v, N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(cudaRS, rhs._v, N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        do_op<T><<<1, N>>>(cudaLS, cudaRS, cudaRV, [] __device__(T l, T r)
                           { return l + r; }); // nvcc doesn't recognize this + operator
        cudaMemcpy(vec._v, cudaRV, N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        cudaFree(cudaLS);
        cudaFree(cudaRS);
        cudaFree(cudaRV);

        return vec;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const vector<T, N> &vec)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            os << (i == 0 ? '[' : ',') << vec._v[i];
        }
        os << ']';

        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int, 3> v0 = {1, 4, 9};
    vector<int, 3> v1 = v0;
    vector<int, 3> v2 = v0 + v1;

    std::cout << v0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << v2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And when I compile I get the following error:

```
$ nvcc ts1.cu --extended-lambda -o ts1
ts1.cu: In function ‘vector<T, N> operator+(const vector<T, N>&, const vector<T, N>&)’:
ts1.cu:49:171: error: ‘::operator+’ has not been declared
   49 |         do_op<T><<<1, N>>>(cudaLS, cudaRS, cudaRV, [] __device__(T l, T r)
      |                                                                                                                                                                           
... followed by a large number of suggestions.


$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Jan__6_16:45:21_PST_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.140
Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.32267302_0
```

OS: Fedora 37

Why does the second approach fail to compile while the first one succeeds and how can I modify the second to get this general approach to compile and run successfully?

Comment: You should only declare the friends inside of the class and define them outside as they are free functions, not member functions. Then it will also become clear that `operator+` needs to be a function template. I don't think that ths is CUDA specific... Offtopic: Your `cudaMalloc`s and `cudaMemcpy`s use `N` instead of `N * sizeof(T)`.

Answer (score 1):

@paleonix provided some suggestions which helped... The following implementation works:

ts1.cu:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class vector
{
private:
    T _v[N];
    T *_cv;

    void upload()
    {
        cudaMemcpy(this->_cv, this->_v, N * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    void download()
    {
        cudaMemcpy(this->_v, this->_cv, N * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    }

public:
    vector() : _v{0}, _cv(0)
    {
        cudaMalloc(&(this->_cv), N * sizeof(T));
    }

    vector(const vector<T, N> &src) : _cv(0)
    {
        std::copy(src._v, src._v + N, this->_v);
        cudaMalloc(&(this->_cv), N * sizeof(T));
    }

    vector(std::initializer_list<T> src)
    {
        assert(size(src) == N);
        std::copy(src.begin(), src.end(), this->_v);
        cudaMalloc(&(this->_cv), N * sizeof(T));
    }

    template <typename S, unsigned int M>
    friend vector<S, M> operator+(vector<S, M> &a, vector<S, M> &b);

    template <typename S, unsigned int M>
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const vector<S, M> &vec);
};

template <typename T, typename F>
__global__ void do_op(T *a, T *b, T *c, F f)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;

    c[i] = f(a[i], b[i]);
}

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const vector<T, N> &vec)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        os << (i == 0 ? '[' : ',') << vec._v[i];
    }
    os << ']';

    return os;
}

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
vector<T, N> operator+(vector<T, N> &a, vector<T, N> &b)
{
    vector<T, N> c;

    a.upload();
    b.upload();
    do_op<<<1, N>>>(a._cv, b._cv, c._cv, [] __device__(T l, T r)
                    { return l + r; });
    c.download();

    return c;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int, 3> v0 = {1, 4, 9};
    vector<int, 3> v1 = {5, 10, 15};
    vector<int, 3> v2 = v0 + v1;

    std::cout << v0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << v2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ nvcc ts1.cu --extended-lambda -o ts1
$ ./ts1
[1,4,9]
[5,10,15]
[6,14,24]
```